# Intellij 10.5: How do you create a rails project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, intellij-idea

I installed the Ruby plugin, which should also support Rails. However, I can't figure out how to create either a new Rails project, or import one that I've created from the command line. Here is what I have tried:

1. File->New Project...
2. Select "Create project from scratch" and click on "Next >" button.
3. Select a location for the project files, and choose "Ruby Module" from the "Module Settings" and click the "Next >" button.
4. Nothing shows up under the "Project SDK:", so I click on the "Configure..." button.
5. This is where I get stuck. I cannot figure out how to select the ruby sdk.

If I click on the "+" button, I can choose "Ruby SDK" from the list. I then choose the "Ruby" symlink from where Ruby is installed. As in /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Ruby, but this does no good.

I have also tried clicking the "Add..." button under the SDK 1.6 Classpath tab. I then select the Ruby directory, which adds the folder to the list, but again, this does not help.

Any pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any Rubies installed in non-Mac-like locations? I'm using rvm without (too many) issues under IntelliJ (and I recommend rvm or rbenv anyway). If not, try an absolute version directory rather than the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should specify a full path to your ruby executable binary (not a directory), then Ruby SDK will be added.